# Architecture pattern: function to handle 2 identical implementations

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture

I have the following problem which I guess I am solving incorrectly given the problem I am facing:

I have an interface `I` and implementations `A, B, C...` I want to somehow express that I can get some results from couples (f(A, A), f(B, B), f(C, C)) and so on. In other words, I want to interface I to express that 2 identical implementations can be combined to produce some results, while others can be not (you can't get any valid result from f(A, B)).

Right now I have the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class A;
class B;
class I{
public:
  virtual int f (const I &other) const = 0;
  virtual int fSpecific (const A &other) const { throw runtime_error(""); };
  virtual int fSpecific (const B &other) const { throw runtime_error(""); };
};

class A: public I{

public:
 A(int a) : a(a) {} 
 int f (const I &other) const override { other.fSpecific(*this); }
 int fSpecific (const A &other) const override { /*logic here*/ return a + other.a; }
 int a;
};

class B: public I{

public:
 B(int b1, int b2) : b1(b1), b2(b2) {}
 int f (const I &other) const override { other.fSpecific(*this); }
 int fSpecific (const B &other) const override { /*logic here*/ return b1*b1 + b2*b2 + other.b1*other.b1 + other.b2*other.b2; }
private:
 int b1;
 int b2;
};

int f(const I &a, const I &b) {
    a.f(b);
}

int main()
{
    cout << f(A(1), A(2)) << std::endl; // prints 3
    cout << f(B(1, 2), B(3, 4)) << std::endl; // prints 30
    cout << f(A(1), B(3, 4)) << std::endl; // throws an error

    return 0;
}
/*and so on*/
```

But I guess I use a wrong architecture. as adding classes results in changing `I`. Are there any better solution to express this such a relation?

Comment: There is no function/method with 2 args. What do you want exactly?

Comment: sorry, the function is then f(I &a, I &b) {return a.f(b); }

Comment: @Solon Add the function to your question. Shouldn't `A` and `B` inherit from `I` and shouldn't one of their methods be public?

Comment: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61607487/edit) your question to clarify. Currently your text is asking for one thing and the code is something completely different

Comment: ...and please show real code. Don't just type code here, this will only add typos. Better make sure it actually compiles before posting. Currently your code provokes more questions than it helps to clarify: What is `result`, why don't `A` and `B` inherit from `I` ? Missing `;` and many others will prevent this to compile

Comment: @solon then you need at least to use a double dispatch if your args are typed with the interface.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I added the code, hope now it's clearer

Comment: What do you expect to get in case of `class C: public A, public B {}`, `f(A(), C())`? If you need to check if that is the same type, use `std:is_same`. If you need to know if the class is convertible into another, use `std::is_convertible`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interface is indeed strange, asking for method which should not be implemented.

We don't have multiple dynamic dispatch, except with `std::visit` of `std::variant`.

So following might help:

```
using V = std::variant<A, B, C>;

int f(const V& v1, const V& v2) {
    struct {
        template <typename T1, typename T2>
        int operator()(const T& t1, const T2& t2) const { throw runtime_error(""); };

        int operator()(const A& a1, const A& a2) const { return a1.a + a2.a; };
        int operator()(const B& b1, const B& b2) const { return b1.b1*b1.b1 + b1.b2*b1.b2 + b2.b1*b2.b1 + b2.b2*b2.b2; };
        int operator()(const C& c1, const C& c2) const { return c1.c * c2.c; };
    } visitor;
    return std::visit(visitor, v1, v2);
}
```

or keeping you hierarchy:

```
using CV = std::variant<const A*, const B*, const C*>;
class I
{
public:
    virtual ~I() = default;
    virtual CV asVariant() const = 0;
};

class A: public I{
public:
 A(int a) : a(a) {}
 CV asVariant() const override { return this; }
 friend int f (const A& a1, const A& a2) { /*logic here*/ return a1.a + a2.a; }
 int a;
};

class B: public I{
public:
B(int b1, int b2) : b1(b1), b2(b2) {}
 CV asVariant() const override { return this; }
 friend int f (const B& b1, const B& b2) {
    /*logic here*/ return b1.b1*b1.b1 + b1.b2*b1.b2 + b2.b1*b2.b1 + b2.b2*b2.b2;
  }
private:
 int b1;
 int b2;
};


int f(const I& i1, const I& &2) {
    struct {
        template <typename T1, typename T2>
        int operator()(const T1*, const T2*) const { throw runtime_error(""); };

        template <typename T>
        int operator()(const T* t1, const T* t2) const { return f(*t1, *t2); };
    } visitor;
    return std::visit(visitor, i1.AsVariant(), i2.AsVariant());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may employ `dynamic_cast`:

```
class I {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void fSpecific (T &other) {
        if (dynamic_cast<T*>(this))
            std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~I() {}
};

class A : public I { 
};

class B : public I { 
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.fSpecific(a);
    B b;
    b.fSpecific(a);
    b.fSpecific((I&)a);

    return 0;
}
```

There are some problems however:

- Multiple inheritance
- Objects need to be dynamically castable (that is why I added a virtual interface)
- Casting to `I` also works.

Comment: `I` should have a virtual destructor. This is what OP is asking for, but I wonder why should `b.fSpecific(a);` compile when anyhow it can only throw an error.

Comment: @idclev463035818, agreed regarding the virtual destructor. I don't get your point regarding "why should compile" though.

Comment: If `b.fSpecific(a);` throws always it is better to make it a compile-time error rather than a runtime error if possible.

Comment: Nothing is easier: you need to implement this method in each derived class. On the other hand, if you need to implement one function in the `I` interface, there is no way for compiler to guess if that is correct: `((I&)b).fSpecific(a);`

Comment: what I wanted to do is to operate only on the interface. I don't know the particular implementations on this stage. I want to be able to write the following code: I &a1 = A(1); I &a2 = A(2); f(a1, a2);

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov I know it is possible, thats why I mentioned the possibility. When one can choose between a compiler error and a runtime error, one should choose the compiler error. Btw I wouldn't care too much about `((I&)b).fSpecific(a);` doing the wrong thing. If a user casts then they either know what they are doing or they just get what they deserve ;)

Comment: No problem. Either `std::is_same` or `std::is_convertible` should work. This however requires a clarification from the OP.